# Pandas/Spark/Time-Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, time-series

Is there any way to transform the following table?

#### Original data:

[image: Original Data]

#### Expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

Number of rows is 400 mln. Any recommendations? In Excel it can be done as following:

1. Copy "ID" and "Time" to a new sheet. Remove duplicates.
2. Copy "Test" column to the new sheet, remove duplicates, paste transpose horizontically.
3. To get "Result" values, use Index Match based on 3 conditions (ID, Time, Test).

Answer (score 1):

You should use pivot function on your dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

pivot_df = df.groupBy("ID","Time").pivot("Test").agg(first(col("Result")))
```